# How is this binary string being used?

Tags: ruby, string, binary, pack

Im studying some ruby code and I see this "varx" variable being used with [0x140,4] <- What does that means? I couldn't find any ruby doc showing that. The varx is something like a binary string.

```
varx[0x140, 4] = [0x4a8acb38 - 0x1c].pack('V')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is replacing 4 "things" in `varx` starting at index 0x140 in `varx` with the data returned from the RHS side.

Example:

```
s="my name is prince";
s[11,6] = "John";
s
=> "my name is John"
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found it : string[offset,count] = newstring